# Prove $ \ (A-B) \cap (A-C) \subseteq A - (B \cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Question:

Prove $ \ (A-B) \cap (A-C) \subseteq A - (B \cup C)$

My attempt:

Take $ \ x\in (A-B) \cap (A -C) \implies x \in (A-B)$ and $ \ x\in (A-C) \implies (x \in A$ and $ \ x\notin B) $ and $ \ (x\in A$ and $ \ x\notin C) \implies x \in A$ and $ (\ x \notin B$ and $ x\notin C) \implies x \in A$ and $ x \notin B\cup C \implies x \in A -(B\cup C)$.

Is my logic and approach correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof is very good.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Please accept the answer below or write an answer of your own and accept it, so that you can close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can in fact show equality between the two sets:
$$
A - (B \cup C) = A \ \cap (B \cup C)^c = A \cap (B^c \cap C^c) \\= (A \cap B^c) \cap (A \cap C^c) = (A-B)\cap(A-C)
$$